# How to assign a variable in MVEL Template

Tags: mvel

I would like to assign variables in an mvel template.

Assuming that my template has only a property `foo` defined, I would like to do the following:

```
@{bar=foo}
@{bar.name}
```

Unfortunately this outputs me the `toString()` of `foo` and then the property name of bar. I would like to do the same but without printing anything with the assignation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(just in case anyone lands here...)*

According to [this documentation](http://mvel.documentnode.com/#code-silent-code-tag), you can use `@code` blocks to execute statements without emitting output.

```
@code{bar=foo}
@{bar.name}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it outputs an error in my case, `Error: cannot assign variables; no variable resolver factory available`